# I am creating a multiple choice question exam project using radio button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

i am getting all my question from my db using angular and i pass the questionid which i m getting from the database the problem is the name of the radio button is generated on runtime and i m not getting that id in javascript to loop all the value and store in array and store that array in database

**Here is my front end code**

```js
  $scope.SubmitAnswer = function () {

            $scope.Username = Cookies.get('userid');
            $scope.Password = Cookies.get('pass');

            $scope.Question = $("input[name='Question']:checked").param($scope.array);

            if ($scope.Username == undefined && $scope.Password == undefined) {
                window.location.href = "Index.aspx";

            }
            else {
                $scope.array  = []
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Question.length; i++) {
                    $scope.array = $scope.array + "" + $scope.Question[i].value+","

                }
                jdata = {
                    "UserID": $scope.Username,
                    "Questionid": $scope.array,
                "Answer":"",
                }

                result = ApiCall.PostApiCall("AICL", "SubmitAnswer", jdata).success(function (dataIn) {
                    $scope.Questionlist = dataIn.AICLList;


                });

            }
        }
```

```html
 <div id="Questionlist" ng-repeat="Q in Questionlist track by $index">
      <h2 class="quiz-question">{{$index+1}}. {{Q.Question}}</h2>
      <ul data-quiz-question="" id="{{Q.Questionid}}">
      <li class="quiz-answer">
       <div class="radio fancy-blue">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="{{Q.Questionid}}"  ng-bind="{{Q.Questionid}}" id=""  checklist-model="Selected.Questionid" value="A">
        <span>A. {{Q.Option1}}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-answer">
       <div class="radio fancy-blue">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="{{Q.Questionid}}"  ng-bind="{{Q.Questionid}}" id=""  checklist-model="Selected.Questionid" value="B">
        <span>B. {{Q.option2}}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-answer">
       <div class="radio fancy-blue">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="{{Q.Questionid}}"  ng-bind="{{Q.Questionid}}" id=""  checklist-model="Selected.Questionid" value="C">
        <span>C. {{Q.Option3}}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-answer">
       <div class="radio fancy-blue">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="{{Q.Questionid}}"  ng-bind="{{Q.Questionid}}" id=""  checklist-model="Selected.Questionid" value="D">
        <span>D. {{Q.option4}}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
      </li>
      
      </ul>
    <button type="button" class="waves-effect waves-light btn gradient-45deg-light-blue-cyan z-depth-4 mr-1 mb-2" id="submit" ng-click="SubmitAnswer()" ng-disabled="submit"> Submit </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular?

Comment: `id=""` could that be your problem? `i m not getting that id in javascript to loop`